# How to remove this duplicate code

Tags: c#, duplicates

I have this same code on two places:

```
if (amountUnit.ToLower().Contains("x"))
{
    string[] amount = amountUnit.Split('x');
    x = amount[0].Trim();
    y = amount[1].Trim();
}
else
{
    x = "1";
    y = amountUnit.Trim();
}
//
unit = textInBrackets.Replace(amountUnit, "");
name = "";
for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
{
    name += someArray[z];
    name += " ";
}
name = name.Trim();
```

The exact code is repeated twice. How to fix it? If i extract it in a new method, I'll have a lot of ref input parameters. Is there another way?
If it's not possible, just the part untill the comments?

Comment: which parameters you indicate in here?

Comment: Looks like you should have two different methods - one for the `x` and `y` and another for the `name`. If you encapsulate `x` and `y` into a structure, you will have one `ref` parameter (or consider _returning_ that struct and changing it in the caller).

Comment: Maybe you can return a more complex struct or class containing all your return data?

Comment: What are your parameters? Why do you want them to be ref, I would avoid that.

Comment: @L-Three I don't want them to be ref. That's why I'm asking here, to avoid using ref. I need to return x and y from the method.

Comment: Well then, just create a new struct as proposed and return it - then map this to your actual variables.

Comment: what code are you talking about that is repeated?

Comment: @Default The whole code from the question. I have it in two places in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like:

```
public struct Parameters
{
    public int X {get; set;}
    public int Y {get; set;}
}

public Parameters ExtractParameters(string amountUnit)
{    
    var parameters = new Parameters();
    if (amountUnit.ToLower().Contains("x"))
    {
        string[] amount = amountUnit.Split('x');
        parameters.X = int.Parse(amount[0].Trim());
        parameters.Y = int.Parse(amount[1].Trim());
    }
    else
    {
        parameters.X = 1;
        parameters.Y = int.Parse(amountUnit.Trim());
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

Usage:

```
var parameters = ExtractParameters(amountUnit);
var x = parameters.X;
var y = parameters.Y;
```

You can also make it an extension method on string.
And of course you best add some exception handling too.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to have two, separate blocks, logically.

One that deals with `x` and `y` - the other with `name`. These should probably be *separate* methods.

Now, you can create a type (class or structure) that encapsulates `x` and `y`, meaning that you only need to pass in one parameter. Instead of passing it by `ref` you can simply *return* it and in the caller replace what you passed in.

Comment: You mean the input parameter will be amountUnit, ok. But how would I not use ref here?

Comment: @petko_stankoski - You return a new instance of it and use that in the caller. As you do with all `string` functions, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your code and your data into a class ;-)

```
public class Point
{
    public Point(string amountUnit)
    {
        if (amountUnit == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("amountUnit");
        }

        if (amountUnit.ToLower().Contains("x"))
        {
            string[] amount = amountUnit.Split('x');
            this.X = amount[0].Trim();
            this.Y = amount[1].Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            this.X = "1";
            this.Y = amountUnit.Trim();
        }
    }

    string X { get; private set; }
    string Y { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need anything very dynamic, how about splitting it into two methods, and doing something as simple as this:

```
public static string GetX(string amountUnit)
{
    return amountUnit.ToLower().Contains("x") ? 
                        amountUnit.Split('x')[0].Trim() : 
                        "1";
}

public static string GetY(string amountUnit)
{
    return amountUnit.ToLower().Contains("x") ? 
                        amountUnit.Split('x')[1].Trim() :       
                        amountUnit.Trim();
}
```